# Click on the button on which the FocusManager

Tags: actionscript-3

I am writing an application for Arduino.There are a lot of buttons in the application that are in MovieClip. I can click on any one using the keyboard or mouse, everything works correctly. But the application will use control from the array. For example, if Data[5]=100, then the TAB keyboard button should be pressed. If Data[5]=600, then Enter should be pressed. At the moment, pressing TAB turns on the FocusManager. The next time you click, the FocusManager moves to the next button. But if Data[5]=600, when I click on the button that is in MovieClip, I get an error.
3 buttons (Btn1,Btn2,Btn3) are on the main stage.
This code works well

```
this[BtnCurentName].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK, true, false));
```

3 buttons (Btn4,Btn5,Btn6) are inside MovieClip "Prop".I can only press them like this.

```
this[BtnCurentName].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK, true, false));
```

This is my test code.

```
package
{
    import flash.events.*;
    import fl.managers.*;
    import flash.display.*;

    dynamic public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        public var fm:FocusManager;
        public var myBtnFocus:InteractiveObject; 
        public var myBtnName:String = "";
        public var BtnCurentName:String = "";
        public var Prop:MovieClip;

        //# /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //# Main code and supporting functions...
        //# /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        public function Main()
        {
            addFrameScript(0, this.frame1);
            
            fm = new FocusManager(this);
            fm.setFocus( this ); //# manually set your button as default //# fm.setFocus( your button );
            
            this.myBtnFocus = fm.getFocus(); //# update the reference to know currently focused
            this.myBtnName = this.myBtnFocus.name; //# extract name from focused
        }

        public function Rendering() : void
        {
            this.Connect.Status.text = String( this.Data[5] ); // view arduino Data[5]
            
            if (this.Data[5] > 0) //# if the button is pressed
            {
                if( ! Boolean(this.chkBtn))//# if the button is not pressed
                {   
                    //# press mouse click (Enter)
                    if ( this.Data[5] > 950 )
                    {
                        //# it works perfectly, BUT if my buttons are inside MovieClip, when pressing Data[5]=600 I get an error 
                        //# TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
                        trace (">> Name for Click is : " + BtnCurentName);                      
                        this[BtnCurentName].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK, true, false));
                        this.chkBtn = true;

                            /*
                            //# results of Trace...

                            >> Got TAB ... Focus is now changed to : Btn1
                            >> Name for Click is : Btn1
                            >> Got Click ... Button name is : Btn1
                            >> Got TAB ... Focus is now changed to : Btn2
                            >> Name for Click is : Btn2
                            >> Got Click ... Button name is : Btn2
                            >> Got TAB ... Focus is now changed to : Btn3
                            >> Name for Click is : Btn3
                            >> Got Click ... Button name is : Btn3
                            >> Got TAB ... with Parent ... Focus is now changed to : Prop.Btn4
                            >> Name for Click is : Prop.Btn4
                            TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.

                            //# end of results
                            */
                    }   
                    
                    //# TAB = go to next button (component)
                    //# if ( (this.Data[5] == 100) || (this.Data[5] == "100") )
                    if ( this.Data[5] > 820 && this.Data[5] < 860 )
                    {
                        //# it works perfectly
                        this.myBtnFocus = fm.getNextFocusManagerComponent(); //# find it as next one
                        fm.setFocus( this.myBtnFocus ); //# then set as current selection (focused)
                        this.chkBtn = true;
                    }               
                }
            }
            else //# if the button is pressed and Data[5]==0, deleting variables
            {
                if( Boolean(this.chkBtn)) 
                {
                    delete this.chkBtn;
                }
            }
            return;
        }

        public function onMouseClick (event:MouseEvent = null) :void        
        {
            if( event.currentTarget.name != null)
            { this.myBtnName = event.currentTarget.name; }
            trace( ">> Got Click ... Button name is : " + this.myBtnName );
        }
        
        public function onFocusedBtn (event:FocusEvent) :void 
        {
            if(event.target.parent.name == "root2")  
            {
                BtnCurentName = String(event.target.name);
                trace (">> Got TAB ... Focus is now changed to : " + BtnCurentName)
            }
            else 
            {
                BtnCurentName = String(event.target.parent.name + '.' + event.target.name);
                trace (">> Got TAB ... Focus is now changed to : " + BtnCurentName);
            }
            return;
        }
            
        function frame1()
        {                     
            this.Btn1.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, this.onMouseClick );
            this.Btn2.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, this.onMouseClick );
            this.Btn3.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, this.onMouseClick );
            
            //# Buttons into MovieClip
            this.Prop.Btn4.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, this.onMouseClick );
            this.Prop.Btn5.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, this.onMouseClick );
            this.Prop.Btn6.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, this.onMouseClick );
            
            //# Focus listener
            this.addEventListener( FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocusedBtn ); 

            return;
        }
    } //end Class Main
    
} //end Package
```

how can I determine in which MovieClip the button is located so that I can press it?

Comment: _"...Determine in which MovieClip the button is located"_ You can try: `trace("Parent name for Btn4 is : " + Btn4.parent.name);` maybe it'll give you a button's parent MC name.

Comment: I changed the code. I have created a FOCUS_IN listener. In the console, I get the name of the parent MovieClip. Created the BtnCurentName variable. But I still can't click the button by name.

Comment: In the code `if ( this.Data[5] > 950 )` before you do the Click listener, what is the trace of `this[BtnCurentName]`?

Comment: BtnCurentName = String(event.target.parent.name + '.' + event.target.name);  "before you do the Click listener, what is the trace of this[BtnCurentName]? " On buttons Bt4, Bt5, Btn 6 I have FocusManager Prop.Btn4 or Prop.Btn5 or Prop.Btn6

Comment: Is the problem solved now?

Comment: No, look edited code

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public function onFocusedBtn (event:FocusEvent) :void 
{
    if(event.target.parent.name == "root2") 
    {
        this.BtnParent = event.target.parent.name;
        this.BtnName = event.target.name;
        trace (">> Got TAB ... Focus is now changed to : " + this.BtnName)
    }
    else 
    {
        this.BtnParent = event.target.parent.name;
        this.BtnName = event.target.name;
        trace (">> Got TAB ... with Parent ... Focus is now changed to : " + this.BtnParent + "." + this.BtnName);
    }
    return;
}
```

Then in your `function Rendering` you can check as:

```
//# press mouse click (Enter)
if ( this.Data[5] > 950 )
{
    if(this.BtnParent == "root2")
    {
        trace (">> Name for Click is : " + this.BtnName);
        this[this.BtnName].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK, true, false));
    }
    else 
    {
        trace (">> Name for Click is : " + this.BtnParent + "." +this.BtnName);
        this[this.BtnParent][this.BtnName].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK, true, false));
    }
    this.chkBtn = true;

}
```

Solved. I get such a trace

```
>> Got TAB ... Focus is now changed to : Btn1
>> Name for Click is : Btn1
>> Got Click ... Button name is : Btn1
>> Got TAB ... Focus is now changed to : Btn2
>> Name for Click is : Btn2
>> Got Click ... Button name is : Btn2
>> Got TAB ... Focus is now changed to : Btn3
>> Name for Click is : Btn3
>> Got Click ... Button name is : Btn3
>> Got TAB ... with Parent ... Focus is now changed to : Prop.Btn4
>> Name for Click is : Prop.Btn4
>> Got Click ... Button name is : Btn4
>> Got TAB ... with Parent ... Focus is now changed to : Prop.Btn5
>> Name for Click is : Prop.Btn5
>> Got Click ... Button name is : Btn5
>> Got TAB ... with Parent ... Focus is now changed to : Prop.Btn6
>> Name for Click is : Prop.Btn6
>> Got Click ... Button name is : Btn6
```

Comment: Ok glad it's solved. I hope you don't have MovieClips inside MovieClips inside MovieClips otherwise the path could get long like `target.parent.parent.parent.name`. So in such a case you have think of alternate way to get same info (like keep all names in a lookup table like Array or such)